# find link with multiple keywords in c# with HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am writing a program that parse a website.

I manage to find a link in the website, but I needed to pass the exact [Innertext](http://html-agility-pack.net/inner-text) words to find it.

I'm looking for a way to do the same thing but to find it by partial inner text

example:

- innertext is: "hi my name is"

I want to be able to find it by putting only

- "hi my"

  ```
      foreach (var title in htmlNodes)
      {
          if (keywords == title.SelectSingleNode("div/h1").InnerText)
          {
              if (color == title.SelectSingleNode("div/p").InnerText)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(title.SelectSingleNode("div/p/a").GetAttributeValue("href", "pas d'addresse"));
              }
          }
      }
  ```

here keywords need to match exactly the innertext in div/h1. I want it to be partial.

here is the html code :

```
<article>
    <div class="inner-article">
        <a style = "height:150px;" href="/shop/shirts/c712g63kx/p1us9bkh7">
            <img width = "150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/146319/vi/qW2Nur88W30.jpg" alt="Qw2nur88w30">
        </a>
        <h1>
            <a class="name-link" href="/shop/shirts/c712g63kx/p1us9bkh7">Tiger Stripe Rayon Shirt</a>
        </h1>
        <p>
             <a class="name-link" href="/shop/shirts/c712g63kx/p1us9bkh7">Teal</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</article>
```

thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to resolve my problem. It was actually quite simple. here is the code:

```
if ((title.SelectSingleNode("div/h1").InnerText).Contains(keywords))
```

Now the problem is to do it with case insensitive.

Comment: If you want case insensivity, use `.ToUpper()` or `.ToLower()` on both your keywords and innertext.

Comment: yeah but it isn't optimise. toupper/tolower create an instance.
I'm trying to figure out how i can use OrdinalIgnoreCase but I don't understand msdn exemples...